# ImageView on top of GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Grid View which contains a textview and 2 image views.first Image View is set to top of other image view.bottom image view is same for all gridview items..
I am now using translate animation and the top image goes under the bottom image...
Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

in your code, take a reference to your image and use the following method:

```
image.bringToFront();
```